# Why my receive method is stopping my iex?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

I wrote the following code on my iex terminal and after that it does not respond anymore, the terminal just stop, like it was expecting something else. What is actually happened?

```
receive do 
    {:hello, msg} -> msg          
    {:world, msg} -> "won't match" 
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`receive` by default has no timeout so the process will be blocked until a message matching any of the pattern is received by the current process. If you're just playing around, you can set a timeout using `after` to make sure this doesn't happen:

```
receive do
  {:hello, msg} -> msg
  ...
after 5000 -> :timeout
end
```

If no message matching the pattern is received in 5000ms, the expression will now return `:timeout`.

Comment: Such incredible thing! Thank you! +1